# How to set .next-folder in another folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have my pages folder in /client folder and would like .next folder in root of project.

I have a project with the following structure:
[image]

Whereby I place pages folder under ./client/pages. Ideally, I would like to place .next folder in root of project.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the next.config.js file to specify the output of the build.

I like to have my folder called _next to make routing easier.

```
module.exports = {
  distDir: '_next',
};
```

So you could make your path traverse one level through the directory with:

```
module.exports = {
  distDir: '../.next',
};
```

Although I would recommend you don't use the .next name and use the underscore instead, this will solve a lot of headaches in production.

```
module.exports = {
  distDir: '../_next',
};
```

An even better solution would be to use a proxy like Nginx to handle the routing for you. So leave your _next folder in the client directory and set the root path to your client folder.